# Need to populate an autocomplete with school names

Tags: php, mysql

I am using php, ajax and mysql to make an autocomplete function, when the user starts to enter the name of their school I use ajax to send the value they entered into a text field to a php function. that function then uses a like %string% to find colleges that match what they entered. I have a couple of issues tho.

For example I have Cal Poly (California polytech) in my database as:

California Polytechnic State University-San Luis Obispo

But usually the user would enter in California Polytech, they would just enter in Cal poly or the phrase for their school name.

but when i type in "Cal Poly" no results show up, i have to type in california to get the cal poly school to show up.

This is just an example and I need it for other schools as well.

Is there any way to improve my database query to make it return results that are even slightly similar without returning things that aren't similar?

Here is my code so far:

Jquery:

```
$(".input-college").keyup(function(){
    var d = $('#search-college-form').serialize();
    var v = $(this).val();
    if (v.length > 4) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/colleges/search_college_names',
            data: d,
            type: "POST",
            success:function(data){
                $(".input-d-down ul").html(data);
            }
        });
    }

});
```

PHP

colleges controller

```
 public function search_college_names() {
        $search = $_POST['college-search'];
        $data['college_list'] = $this->College_Model->search_colleges($search);
        $this->load->view('inputs_views/search-college-dropdown', $data);
    }
```

colleges model

```
public function search_colleges($search) {
$query = $this->db->select()->from('collegenames')->like("names", $search)->get();
return $query->result_array();
}
```

please let me know, I am kinda new to search function using like%%

Thanks

Comment: How would you consider solving this issue without programming. eg how would you break down "cal poly" or "cal uni" to find California Polytechnic in a dictionary

Comment: Because college abbreviations differ so much (based on sounds and such) there isn't much you can do, you can program in special cases for ones you know, but other than that there isn't much.

Comment: Also, try to combine it with fulltext search. That will give you more control over the userinput in your query

Comment: In order to correct some possible typos, you might want to look into http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php

Comment: you can introduce a field or a 2nd table that connects with your primary table on the commonly used names.

Comment: @Martijn Woah, I didn't know that one even existed, awesome.

Comment: you need to play with like clause follow the links it will help you out http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html , http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-like/

Comment: @John: Be carefull though, you dont want to make it process huge amounts of data. String comparing in code is never superfast

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to go about this is to split the search string by spaces and then `AND` them in the query.

For instance, the string `"Cal poly"` would result in a query such as `SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE "%Cal%" AND name LIKE "%poly%"`.

If you need this to be a *really* fast and smart search you should look into [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/), but that's probably serious overkill for your problem.

Comment: I don't see SQL queries in his example, do you?

Comment: He's obviously using a builder which, most likely, produces SQL at the end. You can of course create the above query with that builder, but  I don't think creating that statement with a builder would have made the answer any better.

Comment: just did that, works now to find the schools :) now i just need to figure out how to sort the data by most similar match and then limit the results and I am good, but I think I will accept this. Thanks!

Comment: @cipherous so far, use `->sort()` and `->limit()`